# How to detect FTDI device in use?

Tags: c++, usb, ftdi

I am writting a C++ application which uses several types of FTDI devices via FTD2xx.dll library (I don't use virtual COM ports). I use `FT_CreateDeviceInfoList` function to search connected devices.

The problem comes when I run multiple instances of my application because the function `FT_CreateDeviceInfoList` is not able to deliver any additional information on devices which are currently in use.

I need to distinguish two simple cases:

1. Device is not present in the system.
2. Device is connected, but currently in use.

How shall I do this?

Thank you for your ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Would a lock file do? Have your app create a ~FTDI_DeviceName.lock file somewhere (or .FTDI_DeviceName.lock if on linux-like systems) for each device and check for it's existence.

The existence of the device is then checked by your usual functions, and the lock should make sure you know which ones are in use.

This obviously only works if your app is the only program using these devices.

Comment: Unfortunately the devices can be operated by both official software and my special application, therefore locking will not work in all cases as you write :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

Device is not present in the system.
    You can use GetDeviceList api to return the FTDI list of devices connected
    and use the SerialNumber property or Description property to check for a specific device.

Device is connected, but currently in use.
    With the api OpenBySerialNumber() or OpenByIndex() will fail if the device is already in use.